# Azure Heartbeat displaying status of all Virtual Machines with Color indicators

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, heartbeat

I am trying to write a query in Azure Monitor > Logs which displays the status of all virtual machines. I am currently able to display all VMs (in a selected scope) with their heartbeats but can't mention their status (with a green/red code) in the table.

[image]

My end goal is to display it on Azure Dashboard so that everyone in the team could look at the status of VMs.

I am pretty new to Azure and still trying to understand how it works. Any guidance will be appreciated.

My current simple heartbeat query is

Heartbeat
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Computer

This display the following columns,

Computer
TimeGenerated
SourceComputerId
ComputerIP
Category
OSType

along with other details.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create an Azure Dashboard for checking Status of Azure VM:**

**Go to Azure Portal > Virtual Machines > Click on pin- blade option > Create new.**

[image]

Create a new dashboard, like below.

> Note: If you select a shared option, whoever have RBAC access,they can be able to view the dashboard.

[image]

To change the dashboard view to **Donut Chart**.

Please follow the below steps.

**Click on setting option> View >Summery.**

[image]

Successfully created a dashboard with status.

[image]

Assign the RBAC role to user to view the dashboard.

```
Ex : Monitoring Reader
```